# autocomplete usando um script no ubuntu nao funciona

Tags: ubuntu, autocompletar

O autocomplete  no terminal parou de funcionar apos atualizacao para o ubuntu 14.04. Se eu usar o comando abaixo, funciona:

> java hfs.io.rsegy filename=0314   pressionando tab eu obtenho
>   java hfs.io.rsegy filename=0314-1005_PSTM.sgy
>   Coloquei o comando em um script chamado rsgy e tornei este arquivo executavel: `java hfs.io.rsegy $*`

no arquivo `rsgy`

Usando o comando abaixo no terminal e pressionando tab, parou de funcionar na nova versão o Ubuntu:

> rsgy filename=0314

pressinando o tab, nada acontece.

Comment: O auto complete do seu ubunto não funciona mais com nenhum comando ou é so comandos específicos?

Comment: Só não funciona para o arquivo  rsgy que é um script. Se eu não usar o script, mas sim o comando original, ele funciona. O comando do script funcionava antes da atualização.